# mocha & chai dependencies when running npm install

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, mocha.js, bower, chai

I want to run an Ionic app with Grunt (Yeoman Ionic)
To do this the script runs `npm install` and `bower install`. Then run `grunt` to compile and then `grunt serve` to serve it on local host.

`npm install` does not create peer dependencies with Mocha and Chai which is making `bower install` abort like so:

```
Running "karma:continuous" (karma) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'mocha' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I ran `npm install -g chai mocha` then `npm install` and got the same

```
 npm WARN karma-mocha@0.1.10 requires a peer of mocha@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-chai@0.1.0 requires a peer of chai@* but none was installed.
```

Even though this is a warning it is yielding errors when running `yo ionic`:

```
npm WARN karma-chai@0.1.0 requires a peer of chai@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-mocha@0.1.10 requires a peer of mocha@* but none was installed.
ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/donjohnson/ionicNom/app/app/css' -> '/Users/donjohnson/ionicNom/app/app/styles'
ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/donjohnson/ionicNom/app/app/js' -> '/Users/donjohnson/ionicNom/app/app/scripts'
ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/donjohnson/ionicNom/app/app/img' -> '/Users/donjohnson/ionicNom/app/app/images'
```

This makes grunt serve open a browser page with nothing in it :(

Answer (score 13):

`npm install --save-dev mocha chai` to your project (without the `-g`).

As of version 3, npm does not automatically install [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that with NPM 3, the dependencies won't be installed by default, use this to update:

```
npm install chai@*
npm install mocha@*
```

and then use:

```
npm install
bower install
```